# Status bar color in iOS 6?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to have this status bar in iOS 6?

In previous version of iOS, it has that status bar, but in iOS 6 it seems to follow the navigation bar color..

[image: status bar]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

are the options available apart from default

Comment: hmm this will display black or gray color..i want the status bar color like in my picture..gradient from light gray to dark gray..

Comment: @AppleDelegate this wont work, here it needs to add a custom color, do you have any alternate solutions?

Answer (score 22):

In iOS 6 the status bar color is now automatically determined by the navigation bar colors.  To be specific the color is determined by the average color of the bottom pixel of the navigation bar as seen below: [image]

I am not sure if there is any other way to override this new operation.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to achieve the gradient in the status bar anymore.  You could at least reproduce the flat gray color by using my approach above.

Comment: +1 for the great example images showing what you mean. I didn't know it was "average of bottom row of pixels", and the image shows that very clearly, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by change the status bar properties as follows:

1-Go to your project target.

2-Choose summary tap.

3-Go to status bar section.

4-Customize it as you like.

[image: HOW TO CHANGE]

Comment: These changes only apply to what's shown in the startup image.

Answer (score 2):

I've found out in iOS6, you can not get gray "former default" style. All parameter in info.plist and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

either setting can not give you light gray in iOS6. In iOS5,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

This was what you needed. So iOS6 eliminated gray bar style.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect 'Default' doesn't necessarily give gray in iOS 6.

How about setting the custom tint to gray?