# How to overlap navigation bar by adding view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I want to make a custom side bar by adding a new view to the view controller, the side bar will be in the yellow color background. I want my side bar also to overlap the navigation bar/item (green background color) in my view controller. but the navigation bar/item seems can't be overlapped by my side bar view, it seems only overlap the main view.

I tried to find the answer in stackoverflow, I find this [Overlap navigation bar on ios 6 with other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115240/overlap-navigation-bar-on-ios-6-with-other-view), but the answer is on the Objective-C, I can't read Objective-C :(

What should I do to overlap navigation bar/item ? here is the screenshot of my view controller

[image]

I embed the navigation controller like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of implementations of slide-over or drawer containers.

What you need to do to get above the navigation bar is **CONTAIN** the navigation controller inside another view controller.

The stack would look like this.

- MasterViewController

  - UINavigationController

    - RootViewController
  - Menu

See this one here:

[Swift version of MMDrawerController](https://github.com/sascha/DrawerController)

Comment: thks for your answer, but how do i contain navigation controller inside another view controller? do you mean embed navigation controller inside the view controller? I am sorry, I am a beginner in iOS development

Comment: Typically via storyboard you use "Embed Segue" or you create it programmatically. It is like a master detail view, except the master is the menu and the detail is the navigation controller.

Comment: If this isn't for some sort of assignment or other, you are better off using a cocoa pod like the one mentioned, as it's non-trivial to do, and likely more reliable from a well-tested library

Comment: oh ok, I just knew that there is a pod called MMDrawerController to make side bar like this. Thank you very much for the information

Comment: Yup, I used that one some years ago successfully it was good for the time. This is a swift version. Enjoy

Comment: do you have sample project for this one ? I try to google it but mostly on objective C implementation :(

Comment: Try running the "KitchenSink" project in the source code on GITHUB (link I gave you)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your `UIViewController` hierarchy. For this you'll need three view controllers. First will contain everything, let's call it `MasterViewController`; second—your main content with navigation bar; and third—drawer.

[image: ViewController hierarchy diagram]

In `MasterViewController` instantiate child view controllers and add them to your view controller hierarchy in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
final class MasterViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let drawerViewController = DrawerViewController()
        let mainViewController = MainContentViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

        addChildViewController(drawerViewController)
        addChildViewController(navigationController)

        view.addSubview(navigationController.view)
        view.addSubview(drawerViewController.view)
    }
}
```

Now you have `navigationController.view` that you can place or animate anywhere within `view`.

Comment: thank you very much for your very useful information, but to be honest I am a beginner and it is hard for me to understand if I don't see the storyboard :(  . do you have simple sample project for this one ? sorry to say this. Thanks