# How to add a button above navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navbar

[image: Button above nav bar]

I want to add a button above navbar which can be tapped to return to another view. It's similar to WhatsApp **touch to return to call** view.
I've following code but it overlaps the nav bar.

Is it possible to add a button above nav bar? If yes how to do it?

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:statusBarHeight+20))
button.tag = 12323
button.setTitle("Touch to return to call", for: [])
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
button.backgroundColor = .green
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(button)
self.navigationController?.view.bringSubviewToFront(button)
self.navigationController?.view.clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: This button will automatically appear if you use CallKit.

Comment: It appears only if app is sent to background. AFAIK there is not way to show this when app is in foreground. WhatsApp and Skype use custom view to show this. If it is possible to show when app is in foreground then let me know how to do that.

Comment: You actually need to embed your nav controller inside another view controller and make it a container.. then based on some business logic, you can show the button from the parent view controller and slide down your nav controller, animating it too.

Comment: I've tabs and nav controllers. It's not a new project. I'm not sure if embedding nav bar inside another VC will work for me. I've found what you are saying on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615295/how-to-overlap-navigation-bar-by-adding-view-in-swift I'm not sure how to implement this in my project where I use IB. Can you provide a code to do it?